# When is NSViewController fully initialized and safe to reference all subcomponents?

Tags: xcode, lifecycle, nsviewcontroller

I've read the class reference on NSViewController, but I was still wondering if an instance is fully initialized when it calls viewDidLoad(), or if I should wait for viewWillAppear() or something else.

In particular, I'm using Xcode, and I want to call cellAtRow( x, Column:y ) on an NSMatrix that is connected as an Outlet. Where is the earliest point in the lifecycle I can be certain everything is fully configured?
TY!

Comment: That depends a bit. From where does the matrix get its content? Is it configured at design time, statically in the NIB/storyboard? Is it using bindings? If so, to what is it bound and where does that get its content?

Answer (score 0):

NSViewControllers have a property called viewLoaded that is YES once [loadView] is complete. Since that's where the nib is usually loaded, it should be safe to operate on outlets then.